# "Position" as verb to use in graphical user interface discussions?

Tags: verbs, terminology

What's the correct term to use for "positioning" elements in a graphic user interface?

For example, if I say:

> Where should we position the button A?

Is that a correct (and professional) way to say it?

Comment: Yes. (I would omit the `the`)

Comment: I would use place or put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both “placement” and “position(ing)” are used e.g. in the [Gnome Human Interface Guidelines](http://library.gnome.org/devel/hig-book/2.32/hig-book.html#design-window).

Analogously, both “to place” and “to position” should be fine.

/EDIT: the [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx) almost exclusively use “placement” at the moment.

Comment: Gnome Human Interface could also be interpreted as a communication medium between gnomes and humans...

Comment: @Claudiu that would be a Gnome–Human Interface.